# Convert double array to array (for TCP data transfer)

Tags: vb.net, tcp, arrays, tcpclient

I want to convert a double array to byte array.

For a single double it is working fine, but I'm having trouble converting an entire array. Following is the code:

```
Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 50009)
Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then

    Dim value As Double =  45
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = BitConverter.GetBytes(value)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
```

Now I want to convert an array of doubles to a byte array and send via tcp.

```
Dim values() As Double = {-12.3323, 45, 67}
```

Thanks 
Arun

Comment: Wrong Tag, Not vba, should be vb.net

Comment: Thanks i changed it.

Comment: So, basically, your question is: how do I loop in vb.net ?

Comment: yes, i think so , converting three integers in bytes & combined them in one byte array, send it to network tcp

Comment: They're not integers, they're doubles. An integer doesn't have any decimals.

Comment: [Different types of loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx)

Comment: i am not able find complete solution using loop. i manage to set code to convert three double variable in byte array.

Comment: Dim Vx As Double = 1
        Dim Ax As Double = 1
        Dim Ay As Double = 1
             
        Dim BytArr0() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Vx)
        Dim BytArr1() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Ax)
        Dim BytArr2() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(Ay)
        Dim BytArrF(23) As Byte

        Array.Copy(BytArr0, 0, BytArrF, 0, 8)
        Array.Copy(BytArr1, 0, BytArrF, 8, 8)
        Array.Copy(BytArr2, 0, BytArrF, 16, 8)